# Can a data-scroll-speed tag be added and removed again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to add tag `data-scroll-speed="3"`(myDiv1) to a div when another div's (myDiv2 in example) bottom edge is scrolled above the browser window's bottom edge? And remove the `data-scroll-speed="3"` tag again when myDiv2's bottom edge is scrolled below the browser bottom edge again. Is this possible?

```css
#myDiv1 {
  font-size: 5em;
  margin-top: 70vh;
  display: inline-block;
}

#myDiv2 {
  height: 120vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: orange;
  z-index: -1;
  display: inline-block;
}

#myDiv3 {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv2">
  <div id="myDiv1">
    hello, i am myDiv1
  </div>
</div>
<div id="myDiv3">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps. I have used JQuery for this.

> Note that, I have only added the `data-scroll-speed`attribute. The rest is yours :)

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('#myDiv2').height() - $(window).height()) {
    $("#myDiv1").attr("data-scroll-speed", "3");
  } else {
    $("#myDiv1").removeAttr("data-scroll-speed");
  }
  console.log($("#myDiv2").html());
});
```

```css
#myDiv1 {
  font-size: 5em;
  margin-top: 70vh;
  display: inline-block;
}

#myDiv2 {
  height: 120vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: orange;
  z-index: -1;
  display: inline-block;
}

#myDiv3 {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv2">
  <div id="myDiv1">
    hello, i am myDiv1
  </div>
</div>
<div id="myDiv3">
</div>
```